# vue - use same url multiple times with other anchor

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In my web application I use the same url several times with other anchors. Is it possible to somehow "store" the baseurl somewhere?

My code looks like:

```
  <a
    class="link"
    href="https://google.com/same/index.html#ancor"
    target="_blank">
    {{ $t("labelLearnMore") }}
  </a>
```

`https://google.com` is always the same, can I shorten this somehow in vue that the code looks cleaner?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `a` tag, use the `router-link` provided by `vue-router`.
The code will be:

```
<router-link
  to="/same/index.html#ancor"
  target='_blank'
/>
```

For more informations take a look to the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <a
    class="link"
    :href="baseUrl + '/same/index.html#ancor'"
    target="_blank">
    {{ $t("labelLearnMore") }}
  </a>
```

or es2015

```
  <a
    class="link"
    :href="`${baseUrl}/same/index.html#ancor`"
    target="_blank">
    {{ $t("labelLearnMore") }}
  </a>
```

set baseUrl in your vue data

Comment: where in the vue data?

Comment: Is this a vue template or blade that you've shown here? I think you need to show more of your vue code. Also if the links are only internal then Tinwor's approach is the correct solution.